# Вызвать функцию JS по имени в переменной

Tags: javascript, callback

Есть форма с дата-атрибутом "callback", он содержит название функции, которая должна запуститься после отработки AJAX

```
<form data-callback="test">
// code...
<form>

// по "on submit" отправляю форму
$.ajax({
  // code...
  success: function(data) {
    // здесь надо вызвать функцию "test"
  }
});
```

eval() не предлагать.

Пробовал реализовать через объект:

```
var ObjectName = {
  test : function(){
    // code...
  }
}
```

Объявлять функции как методы класса и потом обращаться по имени метода `ObjectName[callback]()` и это работает, но очень нестабильно, в зависимости о того, где объявлять объект - до или после.

Comment: На крайний случай можно switch использовать

Comment: "это работает, но очень нестабильно" - это Вы что-то неправильно делаете, потому что это правильное решение.

Comment: `в зависимости о того, где объявлять объект - до или после` - вообще все работает в зависимости от того где и что обьявить, обьявите обьект в нужном месте и не имейте проблем.

Comment: Смотря где функция объявлена и как.... например если в глобальном пространстве, то `window['test']()` вполне себе может сработать. если в другом объекте, то также по скобочной нотации

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Может стоит уже вместо `var` -- `let` и `const` использовать? `var` до объявления равны `undefined`, а с `let` и `const` код просто не запустится, они видны только **после** их объявления, и всё будет либо *работать стабильно*, либо не будет работать,

> в зависимости о того, где объявлять объект - до или после.